# Socket is only able to send once

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

These are my basic Python programs for testing TCP sockets.

server.py:

```
import socketserver as serv

class Handler(serv.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        received = self.request.recv(16)
        print('received',received)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host, port = 'localhost', 2000

    with serv.TCPServer((host,port), Handler) as serv:
        serv.allow_reuse_address = True
        serv.serve_forever()
```

client.py:

```
import socket as Socket
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    host, port = 'localhost', 2000
    with Socket.socket(Socket.AF_INET, Socket.SOCK_STREAM) as socket:
        socket.connect((host, port))

        socket.send(bytes('1','utf-8')) # First send
        time.sleep(0.5)
        socket.send(bytes('2','utf-8')) # Second send
```

The server is run first, followed by client. The server prints:

```
received b'1'
```

But I would like it to say this to show that the server received both sends:

```
received b'1'
received b'2'
```

Am I missing something that is required between each sends?

Comment: Have you tried making the server send a response back when receiving a byte from the client?

Comment: your `Handler` has only one `recv` and then returns.

Comment: Put a loop in `handle()`.

Comment: @ateesdalejr That did not work. Why is sending a reply necessary to receive another byte?

Comment: @Daniel I was under the impression that the `serv.serve_forever()` runs the handle continuously in a loop, and that `handle()` is called for every request. What would I need to do to have the server receive separate sends from the client? Or is looping inside `handle()` the proper way to do it?

Comment: No, `handle()` is called once for each connection, not for each message. Also you can't be sure to get all the data with a single `recv()`, that's up to the network layer. That could become an issue if the message sizes get bigger, then you generally can't discern if `recv()` returned because the client did an implicit or explicit flush. For that you'd have to implement a protocol on the application layer.